# The type com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, google-bigquery

Here I am trying to insert CSV data into bigQuery table, I already configured google-cloud-bigquery-1.93.0.jar file in eclipse. But I am getting error for "com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions$Builder". see below code which I am using.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.cloud.bigquery.InsertAllResponse;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.InsertAllRequest;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.InsertAllResponse;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;

public class InsertData {
    public static void uploaddata(String datasetname) throws IOException {
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions
            .getDefaultInstance()
            .toBuilder()
            .setProjectId("my-project-id")
            .build()
            .getService();

    TableId tableIdor = TableId.of(datasetname, "table_name");
    String csvFile = "D:/my-file/my.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader myFile = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String[] beschriftung = null;
    int i = 0;
    Map<String, Object> rowContent = new HashMap<>();
    myFile = new FileReader(csvFile);
    br = new BufferedReader(myFile);
    // read CSV file line by line and upload it into BigQuery
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // get the name of the fields from the first row of the CSV File
        if (i == 0) {
            beschriftung = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            i = i + 1;
            for (int e = 0; e < beschriftung.length; e++) {
                rowContent.put(beschriftung[e], "init");
            }
        } else
        // Format Data for BigQuery and upload the row
        {
            String[] Zeile = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            for (int e = 0; e < Zeile.length; e++) {
                rowContent.put(beschriftung[e], Zeile[e]);
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        InsertAllResponse response = bigquery
                        .insertAll(InsertAllRequest
                        .newBuilder(tableIdor)
                        .addRow(String.valueOf(i), rowContent)
                        .build());
        if (response.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(response.getErrorsFor(0));
        }
    }
    br.close();
    myFile.close();
}
```

}

I am getting syntax error in below lines.

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions
            .getDefaultInstance()
            .toBuilder()
            .setProjectId("my-project-id")
```

Error notification is -

> The type com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

=======
pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>insertdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>insertdata</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>insertdata</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.93.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.90.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I am getting below error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryOptions
    at insertdata.insertdata.InsertDataBigQuery.uploaddata(InsertDataBigQuery.java:24)
    at insertdata.insertdata.InsertDataBigQuery.main(InsertDataBigQuery.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

What would be the solution, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `google-cloud-bigquery-1.93.0.jar`, you have to also configure at least [`google-cloud-core-1.90.0.jar`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-core/1.90.0/google-cloud-core-1.90.0.jar) in Eclipse.

`BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()` returns `BigQueryOptions.Builder` that extends the missing `ServiceOptions.Builder`. This is why you get the error.

For all by Google Cloud BigQuery 1.93.0 required dependencies which may require additional dependencies themselves, see section ***Compile Dependencies*** in [Maven Repository - **Google Cloud BigQuery 1.93.0**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.93.0).

Alternatively, you could use a **build tool like Maven or Gradle**, which will automatically download all necessary dependencies and configure them in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Now compile time error is resolved, but when I am trying to Run jar file and I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryOptions
        at insertdata.insertdata.InsertDataBigQuery.uploaddata(InsertDataBigQuery.java:24)
        at insertdata.insertdata.InsertDataBigQuery.main(InsertDataBigQuery.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions

Comment: please see above pom.xml file

Comment: Make sure the project is configured as Maven project: right-click the project and choose _Configure > Convert to Maven Project_. You do not have to specify the `google-cloud-core` dependency as you get this via `google-cloud-bigquery` dependency (Maven knows what `google-cloud-bigquery` requires).

Comment: @BhageshArora can you confirm if the answers given were enough to solve the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Sergi Muznos, below pom.xml is working for me, after the adding google-cloud jar, we need to fix use the <plugins>

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>insertdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>insertdata</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>insertdata</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
<version>1.93.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
<version>1.90.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
   <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>                
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```